# Adding TextGeometry THREE.js by For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, three.js

i am trying to build numbers along a 3d grid with THREE.TextGeometry()

but it only generates one number.
what is a solution to get this code working properly?

the "current" variable is a number from -10 to 10, skipping the 0
my IDE(PyCharm) tells me "Mutable "Variable is accesable from closure"

i dont know what i am doing wrong and how to solve it, thank you

function createGridNumbersX(size){

```
var grpGridNumbersX = new THREE.Group();
grpGridNumbersX.name = 'grpGridNrsX' ;

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
var fontType = 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json';
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff});

for (i=0; i<(size*2)+1; i++) {

    var counter = i + 1;
    var start = -size - 1;
    var current = start + counter;

    if (i === size) {
        continue
    }

    console.log('current ' + current);

    loader.load(fontType, function (font, ) {

        var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(**current**, {
            font: font,
            size: 0.3,
            height: false,
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
        mesh.name = 'xNr' + i;
        mesh.position.x = current;

        grpGridNumbersX.add(mesh);

    });
}

scene.add(grpGridNumbersX);
```

}
createGridNumbersX(10);

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to wait for the font to load just once

```
var grpGridNumbersX = new THREE.Group();
grpGridNumbersX.name = 'grpGridNrsX' ;

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
var fontType = 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json';
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff});
loader.load(fontType, createText);

function createText(font) {
    for (let i=0; i<(size*2)+1; i++) {

        var counter = i + 1;
        var start = -size - 1;
        var current = start + counter;

        if (i === size) {
            continue
        }

        console.log('current ' + current);

            var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(**current**, {
                font: font,
                size: 0.3,
                height: false,
            });

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
            mesh.name = 'xNr' + i;
            mesh.position.x = current;

            grpGridNumbersX.add(mesh);
    }

    scene.add(grpGridNumbersX);

}
```

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56750403/128511) useful. It also makes one mesh per letter, it just arranges them into a ring instead of a grid.

Comment: thank you, i found the solution, the for loop needed to be inside the creation of the text geometry function instead of the the creation of the text geometry inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The Solution: 
* Make the "For Loop inside the Loader.load"
* Convert the "current variable into a string"

Still working on how to aim each number to the camera, it does it properly the first time i load the scene, but when i move the camera around, the lookat does not update

function createGridNumbersX(size) {

```
var grpGridNumbersX = new THREE.Group();
grpGridNumbersX.name = 'grpGridNrsX';

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
var fontType = 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json';
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});

loader.load( fontType, function (font) {

    for (i=0; i<(size*2)+1; i++) {

        var counter = i + 1;
        var start = -size - 1;
        var current = start + counter;

        if (i === size) {
            continue
        }

        var str = current.toString();

        var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(str, {
            font: font,

            size: 0.2,
            height: false,
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
        mesh.position.x = current;
        mesh.name = 'xAxeNr' + i;
        mesh.lookAt(camera.position);


        grpGridNumbersX.add(mesh);
    }
});


scene.add(grpGridNumbersX);
```

}
createGridNumbersX(10);